# PayPal in React / NextJS (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE, UpgradeFacilitatorAccessToken_error, upgrade_lsat_failure)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Using Paypal in React with NextJS and it does work and go through

I am getting this error, when I click the PayPal Button:

> GET https://b.sbox.stats.paypal.com/v2/counter.cgi?p=uid_590dd7e5bf_mtu6mdi6ntc&s=SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

> graphql_UpgradeFacilitatorAccessToken_error {err: 'Identitysecuretokenserv responded with status 401 for securityContext', timestamp: '1664379113575', referer: 'www.sandbox.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f4009652c48ed', sessionID: 'uid_29066602a3_mtu6mze6ndm', …}

> upgrade_lsat_failure {error: 'Error: Identitysecuretokenserv responded with stat…experience=&allowBillingPayments=true:1320:36969)', timestamp: '1664379113576', referer: 'www.sandbox.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f4009652c48ed', sessionID: 'uid_29066602a3_mtu6mze6ndm', …}

[image]

I have implemented it in react via the `react-paypal-js` package:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';
import Wrapper from '@/components/Wrapper';
import NoHeader from '@/layouts/NoHeader';

const product = {
    description: 'Bread',
    price: 29
};

const CheckoutButton = () => {
    const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

    const handleApprove = (orderID) => {
        // call backend to fulfill order
        console.log('handle approve call');
        setCompleted(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {completed && <div>Thanks a ton</div>}
            <PayPalButtons
                style={{
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    height: 48,
                    tagline: false,
                    shape: 'pill'
                }}
                createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                    return fetch('/api/paypal/pay10', {
                        method: 'post'
                    })
                        .then(function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            return res.json();
                        })
                        .then(function (orderData) {
                            console.log(orderData);
                            return orderData.id;
                        });
                }}
                onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
                    return fetch(`/api/paypal/success/${data.orderID}`, {
                        method: 'post'
                    })
                        .then(function (res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            return res.json();
                        })
                        .then(function (orderData) {
                            console.log(orderData);
                            handleApprove(data.orderID);
                            return orderData.id;
                        });
                }}
                onError={(err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const CheckoutPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Wrapper tw="bg-white flex flex-col pb-28">
                <PayPalScriptProvider
                    options={{
                        'client-id': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
                    }}>
                    Paypal
                    <CheckoutButton product={product} />
                </PayPalScriptProvider>
            </Wrapper>
        </>
    );
};

CheckoutPage.layout = NoHeader;

export default CheckoutPage;
```

Comment: The stats "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE", may just be a tracking/ad blocker but doesn't matter regardless. Unsure what's going on with the rest, try different credentials -- may need a codesandbox to reproduce

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with different credentials. I have been reading your answers about PayPal on here all day today by the way, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Ad Blocker from your browser.